# How come I don't get all the lines with grep and grep -v

Tags: grep

Why does `grep -v POLYGON` remove many more lines than those matching `grep POLYGON`?

```
$ cat BOUNDARIES3D_LV03.nt | grep -v POLYGON  | wc
    249     782  137001
$ cat BOUNDARIES3D_LV03.nt | grep POLYGON  | wc
   2441 2753697 51833677
$ cat BOUNDARIES3D_LV03.nt | wc
   73078 2975809 91746795
```

Is this a bug in grep (using: grep (GNU grep) 2.23) or am I misunderstanding something?

**Update**
It seems that grep aborts at the first matching line containing an invalid character.

Comment: Contender for http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html ?

Comment: This sounds counter intuitive. However, we cannot do much more than guessing without some sample file.

Comment: What is an "invalid character"?

Comment: what is the output of `alias grep` or `which grep`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that grep aborts at the first line containing a byte sequence that doesn't evaluate to a character in the current encoding. The following resolved the issue for me:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```